# How do I enter a SQL Server Name in PYPYODBC which has a backslash in the server name?

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, pypyodbc

I'm having difficulties trying to connect to a SQL Server instance in pypyodbc.  The server name has a backslash in it eg "servername\something", instead of just the servername.

In pypyodbc, i've tried all different variations,

```
Server=servername\something
Server=servername\\something
Server=[servername\something]
Server=[servername\\something]
```

But none of them seem to work.  I get the following error message

**pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.')**

How can I pass the name of the server?

I  can connect to other servers fine as long as they don't have the backslash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the [Microsoft ODBC driver documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx), for the `Server=` argument in your connection string

> To specify a named instance of SQL Server, append \*InstanceName*.

So the question really is "How to get a single backslash into a Python string?"

One way is to use raw string literals (`r""`). This works for me:

```python
conn_str = (
    r"Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};"
    r"Server=PANORAMA\SQLEXPRESS;"
    r"Database=myDb;"
    r"Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    )
conn = pypyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```